# Create setup for asp.net 2.0 application

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have an asp.net 2.0 application that i want to deploy to a server.
I want to make a setup that will install this application on the server.
Also I must be able to configure parameters such as connection strings on the setup and these changes should reflect on the web.config.

I am using .NET Framework 2.0 and VS 2005.

P.S: I understand that searching "asp net application deployment" on google will give me tons of results, but as i have some special requirements and am doing this for the first time, someone with more experience may be able to push me in the right direction.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily deploy your project using [publish wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163448.aspx) (Visual Studio). Take a look at following articles :

1. [Using Web Deployment Projects with Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx)
2. [VS 2005 Web Deployment Projects - by scott gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)